# How to extract the first occurrence of a word (date) from a particular line?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, xlsm

I would like to loop through a column and extract the date and time from the first occurrence of a sales comment to the neighbouring cell.

There could be a variable amount of lines in the cell and multiple entries from Sales, I need the first response date/time.

Inside the cell the lines will always start with date and time, then name, then department, then comment. The cell then has a line break (if that's what you call it when you Alt return in a cell), then the next entry will begin.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Please note that SO is not a free code writing platform, you should at least make an effort to try and solve your problem yourself and we'll be here to help you with problems along the way.

Comment: In addition to what M. Schalk said, when you possibly edit your question with code that you have tried with, also show a few examples of the data cells contents and how the text to be extracted can be identified.

Comment: "Please note that SO is not a free code writing platform, you should at least make an effort ....."

My mistake. I think maybe I have tried the wrong site then.
I haven't tried code on this as I genuinely don't know how to get the result I want. I know how to do a loop, I can use Left/Mid/Right etc, even seen other formulas than can extract. So I have no examples as i don't know where to start.

Thanks for the feedback and direction though, appreciated.

Comment: "....also show a few examples of the data cells contents and how the text to be extracted can be identified."

Sorry I tried to do this in the original post, I guess it is not clear. Extracted data is the date and time of the st occurrence of Sales. I attached an image with an example.

Thanks for the feedback and direction though, appreciated.

Comment: No need for VBA, you can do what you want with a formula -- [`Find`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-C7912941-AF2A-4BDF-A553-D0D89B0A0628) "` - `" (space - dash - space) then get everything to the [`Left`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203D2D2-7960-479B-84C6-1EA52B99640C) of it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume your data put in `B3` and `B4`
2. In `C3`, formula copied down:

`=AGGREGATE(15,6,0+LEFT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B3,CHAR(10),"</b><b>"),"-Sales","<r/>")&"</b></a>","//b[r]"),19),1)`

3. Then, custom cell format to: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Welcome @bosco_yip, thanks for answering! In the future, make use of SO's formatting features just as numbered lists and code formatting (tip: format code and references with `backticks`, using the same key as tilda). In addition to correct answers, SO also values explanations for how a solution works. Given the complexity of your answer, an explanation for `LEFT`, `CHAR`, etc. wouldn't be expected; however, a brief explanation of how you're using `AGGREGATE` and `FILTERXML` would. Good luck and hope to see much more of you here!